# Error using python watchdog lib. AttributeError: 'nt.DirEntry' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python, watchdog, python-watchdog

```
from os import scandir, rename
from os.path import splitext, exists, join
from shutil import move
import time

import logging

from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

source_dir=r'*censored*'
mp3_dir=r'*censored*'

# ? supported Audio types

audio_extensions = \[".m4a", ".flac", "mp3", ".wav", ".wma", ".aac"\]

def make_unique(dest, name):
filename, extension = splitext(name)
counter = 1
\# \* IF FILE EXISTS, ADDS NUMBER TO THE END OF THE FILENAME
while exists(f"{dest}/{name}"):
name = f"{filename}({str(counter)}){extension}"
counter += 1

    return name

def move_file(dest, entry, name):
if exists(f"{dest}/{name}"):
unique_name = make_unique(dest, name)
oldName = join(dest, name)
newName = join(dest, unique_name)
rename(oldName, newName)
move(entry, dest)

class MoverHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
\# ? THIS FUNCTION WILL RUN WHENEVER THERE IS A CHANGE IN "source_dir"
\# ? .upper is for not missing out on files with uppercase extensions
def on_modified(self, event):
with scandir(source_dir) as entries:
for entry in entries:
name = entry.name
self.check_audio_files(entry, name)

    def check_audio_files(self, entry, name):  # * Checks all Audio Files
        for audio_extension in audio_extensions:
            if name.endswith(audio_extension) or name.endswith(audio_extension.upper()):
                dest = mp3_dir
                move_file(dest, entry, name)
                logging.info(f"Moved audio file: {name}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
path = source_dir
event_handler = MoverHandler()
observer = Observer()
observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
observer.start()
try:
while True:
time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
observer.stop()
observer.join()

No matter what I do i keep getting the same error AttributeError: 'nt.DirEntry' object has no attribute 'rstrip' Im new to coding and copied this off a youtuber. No matter what i change cmd gives me the same error. I dont know what the problem is and cant find anything online
```

No matter what I do i keep getting the same error AttributeError: 'nt.DirEntry' object has no attribute 'rstrip' Im new to coding and copied this off a youtuber. No matter what i change cmd gives me the same error. I dont know what the problem is and cant find anything online

Answer (score 0):

The `rstrip()` method is called on name to remove any trailing whitespace from the file name. However, the `os.DirEntry` class doesn't have a `rstrip()` method, so Python raises an `AttributeError`.

What you can do is in you `def check_Audio_Files()` function add this line in the starting of it before the *for loop*:

```
name = name.strip()
```

So your function will look something like this:

```
def check_audio_files(self, entry, name):
    name = name.strip() 
    for audio_extension in audio_extensions:
        if name.endswith(audio_extension) or name.endswith(audio_extension.upper()):
        dest = mp3_dir
        move_file(dest, entry, name)
        logging.info(f"Moved audio file: {name}")
```

essentially what this line does is by callin `strip` on `name` it clears any whitespace around that file and the `endswith` will work properly

Comment: I updated the check audio files function to look like this but it changed nothing. Is there something else im missing?

Comment: @ayevee under your move handler class the on_modified function is not correctly indented